# php/laravel how to transform number from 1 to 2^31-1 into hexadecimal number which contains e.g. 15 digits evey time

Tags: php, laravel, hash, cryptography

hello i'm working with laravel making something like social site,

users profiles are /users/id

i would like to hide user's ids behind something like hash but in hexadecimal form with every time same length

ideal would be if it cant be retrieved back to original number

yes i could just attach random number to each user but there would be every time check if that number isn't already attached to another user
i tried $id_transform = hexdec( substr ( md5 ( md5 ( $id_transform )) , 10 , -10 )); but that doesn't create unique and same length strings

Comment: You're always going to have a chance of collision trying to do it this way, so no matter what you will have to check if it exists before you save it.  If you want to be virtually positive it was unique you'd have to use the ID itself (inherently unique), or something longer like a GUID which has 2^128 possibilities and will realistically never collide.

Answer (score 2):

Sound like you want to encrypt your IDs.

One simple way of doing this in PHP might be:

```
$id = 12345;
$key = "example key";

$encrypted_id = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt(
    pack("P", $id), "BF-ECB", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
));

print "$encrypted_id\n";
# -> 662b480853d3cc20

$decrypted_id = unpack("P", openssl_decrypt(
    hex2bin($encrypted_id), "BF-ECB", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
))[1];

print "$decrypted_id\n";
# -> 12345
```

Several very important notes:

1. This is not especially secure. It's just enough to make the sequence of values less obvious.
2. The input `$id` must be a non-negative integer. The maximum value is 2<sup>64</sup>-1, which should be fine for most applications. Note that this code cannot handle negative IDs.
3. Validate your inputs. The encrypted ID will always be 16 hexadecimal characters; any other value should be thrown out.
4. `$key` must be a secret string, between 4 and 56 characters long. It should be different for each different type of ID you're encrypting -- otherwise, an attacker can swap encrypted IDs around between different contexts. It **must not** be used for any other encryption in your application.
5. A garbage ID will *usually* result in a very large number as the decrypted ID. If you know that IDs in your application will always be less than 2<sup>32</sup>, you can compare the result to that to identify values which are likely to be invalid. However, keep in mind that there is always a small possibility that a random input will turn out to be a valid ID.
6. Don't try to substitute in another cipher for `BF-ECB` (Blowfish, ECB mode), or to change the packing, unless you are **extremely** sure of what you are doing. The fact that Blowfish uses an unusually small 64-bit block size is critical to this application.

Answer (score 1):

The common reason for people wanting to encrypt or obfuscate URL parameters is because the parameter could be abused to leak information - such as when user IDs are sequential, which means you can increment or decrement them to easily find other users, or when you put private information on a page accessed with a predictable identifier.

The best solution to this problem is to **not have it in the first place**. If you make your user IDs a random character sequence of, say, 10 or 15 characters, your problems will vanish:

- Given one ID, you gain no information about how to guess other IDs
- Collisions are extraordinarily unlikely, and can still be tested for reasonably cheaply (databases are good at this!)

Note that this does not keep user IDs secret - if their public profile is at `/profile/foobar`, then everyone will know that their ID is `foobar`. However, the security of your system really shouldn't depend on keeping a public identifier a secret!

I've skipped over the security pitfalls that can come from trying to roll some kind of URL parameter encryption. You can read more on the topic of *(not!)* encrypting URL parameters here: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php